# TypeScript consdering `undefined` as `any` - why?

Tags: typescript

Here's my code:

```
const x = { a: 1, b: undefined }

// x.b is being considered `any` instead of `undefined`
```

Here's a screenshot demoing the problem:

[image: A screenshot of VSCode an X variable that has an object assigned to it, composed of two properties: a that is 1, and b that is undefined. The screenshot also displays the error, which is TypeScript understanding b, which is undefined, as any.]

[In the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3jAhgLhgRgDQwBG2ArmACYCmAZgJZiXkwC+AUHAHSGsD0PAegH4gA), it is working properly, which leads me to think it is something related to my config. But what could be causing it?

For what it's worth, this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "dom", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

Some extra info:

- TypeScript version: 4.7.4
- Editor: VSCode 1.70.1
- OS: MacOS Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: [A screenshot is worth less than a copy/paste of the code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, [I cannot reproduce this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3jAhgLhgRgDQwBG2ArmACYCmAZgJZiXkwC+AUHAHSGsD0PAegH4gA)

Comment: Weird, what does it think of `x.a`? Maybe it's the just in the editor? Try restarting editor TS server.

Comment: @AlexWayne You're right. Screenshots are bad. Question properly editted. By the way, thank you for sharing your playground -- but my question still remains, why am I getting `b` as `any` instead of `undefined`?

Comment: I am using `VSCode`.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita It thinks `x.a` is a `number`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a reproduction of [your code in the TypeScript Playground with your TSConfig applied](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&declaration=false&importHelpers=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=false&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=false&noImplicitOverride=false&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedParameters=true&noUnusedLocals=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3jAhgLhgRgDQwBG2ArmACYCmAZgJZiXkwC+AUHAHSGsD0PAegH4gA):

```ts
const x = { a: 1, b: undefined }
x.b
//^? (property) b: any
```

and here is the same code with `strictNullChecks` enabled:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&declaration=false&importHelpers=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=false&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=false&noImplicitOverride=false&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedParameters=true&noUnusedLocals=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3jAhgLhgRgDQwBG2ArmACYCmAZgJZiXkwC+AUHAHSGsD0PAegH4gA)

```ts
const x = { a: 1, b: undefined }
x.b
//^? (property) b: undefined
```

The documentation for [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) includes this information:

> When `strictNullChecks` is `false`, `null` and `undefined` are effectively ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at runtime.

Because the type of `x.b` is `undefined`, there is no type information remaining after the exclusion of the types above, so the only remaining options are `any` and `never`, and because you have disabled [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) settings as well, you are left with `any`.

Comment: Touchè! By enabling `strictNullChecks` and restarting the editor, it is now considering `b` as `undefined` instead of as `any`. Thank you for the answer and thank you for pointing out the documentation as well.